The vtkActor show in multi renderwindow problem
There are two vtkRenderWindow objects, each with two vtkRenderer objects, and the layers have been set. The vtkActor is initially set to the lower-level vtkRenderer of each vtkRenderWindow, and it displays normally.
Now, after changing the color and opacity of the vtkActor, if remove it from the lower-level renderer of each window and add it to the higher-level renderer, the vtkActor will only display correctly in the first rendered window. In the second rendered window, the vtkActor disappears.
void MoveActorToTop(vtkSmartPointer<vtkProp> actor)
{
    if (leftWin_ != nullptr)
    {
        leftWin_ ->loewerRenderer_->RemoveActor(actor);
    }

    if (rightWin_ != nullptr)
    {
        rightWin_ ->loewerRenderer_->RemoveActor(actor);
    }

    if (leftWin_ != nullptr)
    {
        leftWin_ ->upperRenderer_->AddActor(actor);
    }

    if (rightWin_ != nullptr)
    {
        rightWin_ ->upperRenderer_->AddActor(actor);
    }
}

After
Left window:

Right window:

